# Perl packages for statistics - multiple regression

Tags: perl, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I am new to perl and looking for a package that includes a code to calculate multiple regression.

Something like OLS that is presented here:

[wikipedia - estimation methods for multiple regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Estimation_methods)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general your starting point when looking for Perl packages - if not Google - would be [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/).

There is a package called [Statistics::OLS](http://search.cpan.org/~smorton/Statistics-OLS-0.07/OLS.pm) - it's old, but you could look at the code there.

A CPAN search for ["statistics regression"](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=statistics%20regression&mode=all) returns 15 packages that you could peruse.

Comment: Thank you! I did find something that looks very useful here: http://search.cpan.org/~iawelch/Statistics-Regression-0.53/Regression.pm